# Can't mass-assign protected attributes for nested form using cocoon and simple_forms in Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

**The Problem:**

I am getting an error message when submitting my form that says:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in AdmissionRecordsController#create
>
> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admission_record

**My Setup:**

I am using Rails 3.2.3, with extra gems including Cocoon 1.0.14 and Simple_Form 2.0.2

**The View:**

My `app/views/admission_records/_form.html.haml` looks like:

```
= simple_form_for [@admission, @record] do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :vital_signs, @record.vital_signs.build do |vs|
    = render :partial => "vital_sign_fields", :locals => { :f => vs }
    = link_to_add_association "Add Vital Signs", f, :vital_signs
  = f.submit
```

And my `app/views/admission_records/_vital_sign_fields.html.haml` looks like:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.label :sbp
  = f.text_field :sbp
  ...
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove Vital Sign"
```

What I am basically trying to do is that I have a resource called AdmissionRecord nested within another resource called PatientAdmission (`route.rb` shown below). I have another resource called `VitalSign` which I want to be able to create via a nested form (using cocoon and simple_form) when creating the `AdmissionRecord`

My `config/routes.rb` file looks like:

```
resources :patient_admissions do
  resources :admission_records
end
```

**The Models:**

My `app/models/patient_admission.rb` looks like:

```
class PatientAdmission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admission_records, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My `app/models/admission_record.rb` looks like:

```
class AdmissionRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient_admission
  has_many :vital_signs, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vital_signs, :rejects_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :vital_signs_attributes
end
```

And my `app/models/vital_sign.rb` looks like:

```
class VitalSign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admission_record
  attr_accessible # just fields that appear in the form
end
```

**The Controller:**

The `new` and `create` methods in my `AdmissionRecordsController` looks like:

```
before_filter do
  @admission = PatientAdmission.find(params[:patient_admission_id])
end

def new
  @record = @admission.admission_records.build
end

def create
  @record = @admission.admission_records.build(params[:admission_record])
  @vital_sign = @record.vital_signs.build(params[:vital_signs])
  @vital_sign.save
  if @record.save
    # Flash success and redirect to the right place
  else
    # Flash error and render :new
  end
end
```

**The Plea:**

Please help me find where I'm going wrong. I've googled for hours and have looked at other examples and source code for demo apps such as those found in [cocoon_simple_form_demo](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/views/projects/_form.html.slim), but still can't seem to fix this error. If there's any other piece of information needed to debug this problem, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add logs for this request? Also in latest Rails all attributes are protected by default. So when you write `.build(params[:admission_record])` you should specify attributes as accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just had this problem and fixed it by entering one line of code in the belongs_to model.

```
# patient_admission.rb
Class PatientAdmission < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admission_record_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admission_record

  ...
end
```

Here is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050083/in-nested-form-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes) solution to it :)