# in nested form- Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have read through several threads and nothing so far. I am trying to nest one form in another. I am getting the can't mass assign protected attributes error. \

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:46:in `new'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:46:in`create'

Projects_controller.rb

```
 def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])


respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

project.rb

```
  WF::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :line_items


    resources :projects do
      resources :line_items
    end

   devise_for :users
   get 'about' => 'pages#about'
   get 'Production' => 'projects#index'
   root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

here is the error...
    ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ProjectsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: line_item

here is my project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :quantity
    # may be unnessary
    attr_accessible :line_items_attributes


    belongs_to :user
    has_many :line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: For future reference, it helps to include the exact error message (so we can see what attribute is mass assign protected).

Comment: Would you mind posting your form? I suspect that may be where the error is originating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to create line items through your project model, you'll need to make sure you have the following lines in your `Project` model:

```
# project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :line_items_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is trying to protect you from accidentally assigning values you don't mean to.

You can tell Rails what values are ok to assign in this way:

```
attr_accessible :value1, :value2
```

If you add that line to the top of the `Project` **model** (replace `:value1` and `:value2` with the actual names of your columns), it should allow you to do what you're attempting.

For more info, here's [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class).

Comment: now i am being givin this error... undefined method `attr_accessible' for ProjectsController:Class

Comment: That line should go at the top of your model, not the controller.

Comment: I don't have it in my controller.<br>

Comment: I don't have it in my controller, I had something else that was triggering it, from when i was trying to debug it. I have cleared that and still have your advice in my model. The error it gives me for this is... Can't mass-assign protected attributes: line_item.